# Как убрать "Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу"?

Tags: windows, c++

Как можно убрать "Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу"? Она мне мешает. Я хочу, чтобы вышло "1.", а потом я мог записать что-то, а при нажатии после этого Enter курсор перешел на новую строку и показывала "2.". Поможете?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "1.";
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN)) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 1001; i++)
        cout << i << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Странная идея править вопрос (менять код в вопросе) так, что смысл ответов теряется.

Answer (score 2):

```
system("PAUSE");
```

Это строка выводит сообщение и ожидает ввода. Вместо нее необходимо просто читать ввод, например:

```
std::cin.get();
```

Comment: спасибо за хорошую информацию о "system(pause)"

Comment: **`GetAsyncKeyState();`** вернёт только опущена ли клавиша (нажата)...

Comment: Добавь **`std::cin.get();`** сразу после **`cout << "1.";`** Может быть заработает твой _индусский_ код :)

Comment: а как сделать, точнее какой код будет соответствовать тому, что если нажать на энтер, то i увеличится на 1? т.е сперва он показывает 1., потом после нажатия на энтер, то под ним будет 2., и т.д

Comment: Что-то вроде:  

    #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
            cout << i << endl;
            std::cin.get();
        }
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

Comment: да, сработал. А откуда я могу про это все прочитать? Ну про "getch", "->", "::" и т.д и включая про std::cin.get();? Что посоветуешь?

Answer (score 2):

[getch](http://proginfo.ru/getch/) - это сокращение от Get char. Означает, буквально, "Дай мне символ".

Answer (score -1):

**`system("PAUSE");`** заменить на **`Console.ReadLine();`**

Ещё вариант:
1) подключи

```
#include <conio.h>
```

2) замени **`system("PAUSE");`** на

```
getch();
```

Comment: ошибку на него выдает

Comment: Может быть путаю что-то с C#

Comment: кажется так и есть

Comment: дописал, попробуй getch();

Comment: спасибо, а какую функцию играет getch()? можешь коротко рассказать?

Comment: Функция getch читает без эхо-отображения отдельный символ
прямо с консоли. Напечатанные (введенные) символы не имеют
эхо-отображения.

Comment: `_getch();` - так будет работать.